# Checking which WHERE criteria gives max records

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM CRMCSVFILE 
WHERE Email_Address_Txt = 'someemail' 
OR TELEPHONE_NUM = '123456789' 
OR DRIVER_LICENSE_NUM = 'fdisa124' 
OR RENTER_NAME_TXT = 'bob'
```

Is there a way to tell which one of these OR criteria spits back the most records??

My table can have multiple repeats of any of the above fields, i want to know which of these fields listed in the WHERE statement returned the max results, is that possible in SQL?

Comment: `iif(Email_Address_Txt = 'someemail', 1, 0) + iif(TELEPHONE_NUM = '123456789', 1, 0) + ...`

Comment: hey juergen would you mind posting that as an answer with a small explanation? i am rather new to SQL and do not understand.

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT f.*
FROM (SELECT f.*,
             IIF(Email_Address_Txt = 'someemail', 1, 0) as condition_1,
             IIF(TELEPHONE_NUM = '123456789', 1, 0) as condition_2,
             IIF(DRIVER_LICENSE_NUM = 'fdisa124' , 1, 0) as condition_3,
             IIF(RENTER_NAME_TXT = 'bob', 1, 0) as condition_4
      FROM CRMCSVFILE f
     ) f
WHERE condition_1 > 0 or condition_2 > 0 or condition_3 > 0 or condition_4 > 0;
```

This provides an indicator for each of the conditions, so you can see what matches each row.

EDIT:

Oh, if that is what you want:

```
SELECT condition_1, condition_2, condition_3, condition_4, count(*)
FROM (SELECT f.*,
             IIF(Email_Address_Txt = 'someemail', 1, 0) as condition_1,
             IIF(TELEPHONE_NUM = '123456789', 1, 0) as condition_2,
             IIF(DRIVER_LICENSE_NUM = 'fdisa124' , 1, 0) as condition_3,
             IIF(RENTER_NAME_TXT = 'bob', 1, 0) as condition_4
      FROM CRMCSVFILE f
     ) f
WHERE condition_1 > 0 or condition_2 > 0 or condition_3 > 0 or condition_4 > 0
GROUP BY condition_1, condition_2, condition_3, condition_4
ORDER BY count(*) DESC;
```

Comment: Then you need add some agregation to know what condition give you the most rows like `SELECT SUM(condition_1),  SUM(condition_2), SUM(condition_3), SUM(condition_4)`

Comment: Gordon Linoff, thank you!! Its almost there! I believe @JuanCarlosOropeza is getting at what i mean, any idea on how to incorporate that into your query?

Comment: Just use the Gordon query as a subquery and add my `SELECT` wrapping that